# MS SQL to MySQLconversion - Recursive CTE

Tags: mysql, sql-server, common-table-expression

i'm trying to convert this MsSQL to MySQL any idea how this can be done?

```
WITH Hierarchy(id, ciid1, name, parent, myLevel)
     AS (SELECT id,
                ciid1,
                name,
                parent,
                0 AS myLevel
         FROM   cities_new c
         WHERE  c.id = 2222
         UNION ALL
         SELECT c.id,
                c.ciid1,
                c.name,
                c.parent,
                ch.myLevel + 1
         FROM   cities_new c
                INNER JOIN Hierarchy ch
                  ON c.parent = ch.ciid1)
SELECT count(id) AS total
FROM   hotels_new
WHERE  id NOT IN( 69912, 70717, 75347 )
       AND ciid IN(SELECT id
                   FROM   Hierarchy)
```

Comment: Similar thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071333/mssql-to-mysql-data-transfer

Comment: i'm not trying to migrate MsSQL to MySQL just trying to convert the MsSQL query to MySQL

Comment: MySQL does not support recursive queries. Is there a known maximum hierarchy depth?

Comment: i know that recursive queries are not supported thats my problem i need to find a work around for MySQL. The depth max is 7